# Possible to receive compensation as part of a class right after the submission deadline?

Tags: united-states, business, consumer-protection, class-action, settlement

A friend and I learned that we are a members of a class ***moments before*** the deadline to submit the required forms for the settlement.  That deadline was approved by a judge, and therefore I think it is legally binding.

The settlement funds have ***not*** been distributed.

We tried submitting the legal forms through the court-appointed claim administrator's online system, but it repeatedly crashed while we desperately tried to submit the forms.  We captured a screenshot.

Is there any way to receive compensation as part of the class, or are we just out of luck?